# How do I delete a file that is in use by another process?

Tags: windows, filesystems, overwrite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I delete a 'locked' file?](https://superuser.com/questions/13291/how-do-i-delete-a-locked-file)

More specifically, I'm trying to rename or overwrite a file, and get the message

> Access Denied. Make sure the disk is not full or write-protected and the file is not currently in use.

Is there a way to find who / what's using the file, and kick them off it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**[LockHunter](http://lockhunter.com/)** is a foolproof file unlocker.

> It is a tool to delete files
>   blocked by something you do not know.
>   LockHunter is useful for fighting
>   against malware, and other programs
>   that are blocking files without a
>   reason. **Unlike other similar tools
>   it deletes files into the recycle bin
>   so you may restore them if deleted by
>   mistake**.

Key Features

> Shows processes locking a file or
>   folder
>
> Allows to unlock, delete, copy or
>   **rename** a locked file
>
> Allows to kill locking process
>
> Allows to remove locking processes
>   from hard drive
>
> Integrates in to Explorer menu
>
> It deletes files into the recycle bin,
>   so you may restore them if deleted by
>   mistake
>
> Supports both 32 and 64bit Windows

as for your question:

> Is there a way to find who / what's
>   using the file?

[image]

*LockHunter is freeware.*

Comment: looks good. does it do remote machines, by any chance?

Comment: if you install the program on the remote machine ...

Answer (score 5):

[Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) is another cool app :)

Comment: Unable to find a way to download from that page. Any link that seems like it should download it just leads to a 404 instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find out who/what is using a particular file use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)

Comment: you're much better of with AnVir Task Manager instead (even the free version beats Process Explorer by a country mile :) http://www.anvir.com/taskmanager/

Comment: something beats process explorer by a country mile? That's an insta-download!

Comment: nice. Got to watch out for toolbar invasion during install, but the app looks pretty sweet. What happens after 20 days?

Comment: Nick, I see you've set aside this special time to humiliate yourself in public. :) "Portable ZIP archive of AnVir Task Manager Free" no installation, no toolbars, no 20 days evaluation period, zip, zilch, nada ... tsss

Comment: oh - so you meant to link me here http://www.anvir.com/download.htm instead. I feel justly humbled for clicking the big shiny green button at the end of your link :)

Comment: in a comment i refrain from a detailed program description, if i would have posted this program as an answer/solution, i would have outlined that the software is free and indeed portable, with the according links, as usual. :) however, a task manager/process explorer isn't really the tool we're looking for here.

Answer (score 1):

For remote machines, if the file is on a network share, you can access the domain controller/member server through computer management (Start->Run->compmgmt.msc) if you have the credentials.

Right-click on the top of the hierarchy (Computer Management (Local)), and select "Connect to another computer". Locate the appropriate server with the file and once connected, expand to Shared Folders -> Open Files. You can then right click any file and disconnect a user from it.

This method only works if you have access to the server. Locally, use the previously mentioned Unlocker.