# How do I bypass "Cannot Delete; file open in another location"?

Tags: file-management, file-permissions

I've been trying to re-install an application, but of course, you have to delete it first, right? Well wrong in my case. Ive been trying to delete it, even going as far as going directly into file location and deleting files one by one.

However, once I get to a certain file, it states `Error, cannot delete file; open in another location`. This has been happening for multiple programs not just one. I even go to that file location that it says is still open and try to delete that one. Its just goes back and forth. Honestly, it's annoying.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I delete a file that is in use by another process?](http://superuser.com/questions/51608/how-do-i-delete-a-file-that-is-in-use-by-another-process)

Comment: What is your operating system?

Answer (score 0):

The full detailed answer depends on what operating system you're dealing with. But essentially, you have to either terminate the program which is holding the file lock, or you have to forcibly break the lock. Then you'll be free to delete the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on OSX, Linux or another Unix alike, you can open your favourite terminal and run:

```
rm -f path-to-file
```

It will remove the file even if it is being used. The file will still be visible to any process that is currently using it however. But it will be gone forever once the last process stops using the file.