# Does anyone know of an equivalent of WhoLockMe that works on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7: File In Use when deleting file](https://superuser.com/questions/73255/windows-7-file-in-use-when-deleting-file)

The original simply doesn't function, at least not under x64.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can run [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653), press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, and type the filename to see a list of open handles to that file.

You can also use [LockHunter](http://lockhunter.com/)

Comment: +1. Process Explorer worked literally as you described. I ctrl-f-ed the directory I couldn't remove and it showed some buried-between-my-open-apps instance of notepad blocking it.

Comment: It should be noted that process explorer has to be run as adminstrator. Ran it on Windows 10 as normal user and it didn't work.