# Windows 7 can not delete a file - file in use

Tags: windows-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7: File In Use when deleting file](https://superuser.com/questions/73255/windows-7-file-in-use-when-deleting-file)

I searched via google and saw that many people have this problem but no definite problem. It says it is in use with explorer but it is not. Do you know any solution without killin explorer exe and delete via cmd command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give the program [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) a shot.  Not only is it **free** and compatible with **all versions of Windows** from 2000 up to 7, it allows you to "unlock" file handles from processes *without* terminating them (of course, you are also given the latter option).

This is the only utility I've found to date which allows you to do this (unlock file handles without terminating processes or rebooting a computer).

Comment: yes this program may solve but i am looking for windows related solution

Comment: This is a Windows program.  Install it (or download the portable version if you don't like installing stuff), try to delete the program, and it should pop up automatically.  Then just click "Unlock" and try to delete it again.  Let me know what happens.

Comment: MonsterMMORPG, you dont want to kill Explorer, you dont want to use Unlocker, you dont want to use the cmd shell... 
I think unlocker is the way to go, it's and EXCELLENT utility

Comment: Unlocker has both a shell-extension to allow you to view open handles to a file and close them on demand, and a background app that detects when you try to delete a locked file and pops automatically pops up its window. In any case, be aware that forcibly closing a handle to a file (whether or not you subsequently delete it) will probably lead to the program that had the open handle crashing at some point. You may not want to kill Explorer, but its almost certain that it will eventually crash if you force one of its handles closed.

Answer (score 0):

Boot into Safe Mode Command Prompt Only. Then change to the directory and delete the file. Are you sure the file is not important to Windows' operation?

Comment: What is the name of the file?

Comment: i read thorugh internet and some says that even safe boot is not solving the issue

Comment: KCotreau file is mkv name is standart english letter

Comment: Normal Safe Mode it may not, but you probably will in Safe Mode Command Prompt Only. There is no GUI. You just boot to a command prompt.

Comment: cmd command is working but a very hard solution and too much time consuming

Comment: You can listen or not...it is not hard, not very time consuming, but if you want to get rid of it, you can try the other way, or you can try my way. Good luck.

Comment: Um, boot into safe mode? The OP doesn’t even want to restart Explorer.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG, [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) is ***very*** easy. If you install its background assistant, you don’t even have to do anything, it will automatically pop up when you try to delete a locked file; and *yes*, it **is** for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

SysInternal's Process Explorer also closes handles. Also free. Unlike Unlocker, it does NOT require an install.

Comment: Unlocker has a portable version (if you’re willing to forgo the shell-extension and tray-assistant). Yes, Process Explorer can let you view and close handles, but I for one consider it *way* overkill for that one purpose, and even if you have other uses for it, using it specifically for this purpose is more work than it’s worth (especially when other tools can do it quicker).