# Find out what app is using a file under Windows

Tags: windows, file-descriptors, tracing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7: File In Use when deleting file](https://superuser.com/questions/73255/windows-7-file-in-use-when-deleting-file)

Sometimes I can't delete a file because it's being used by some unknown applications. How can I find out what apps?

Answer (score 1):

[Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) is a great tool for this.

- It lists all applications that are locking a file (or directory).
- It closes the handle without terminating the application that is locking the file.

Make sure you download the 64-bit version if yiu have a 64-bit OS.

Comment: I'm a big fan of Unlocker, used it quite a few times.

Answer (score 1):

I use [SysInternals' Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653). Search for the locked file. Not only will PE tell you which application locked it, but also what thread in that application opened it. In certain cases (only recommended if you know what you're doing!) you can get away by killing one thread, rather than an entire application.

At any rate, it will tell you who locked the file.

Comment: Please check out: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/787/high-reputation-users-having-trouble-understanding-super-user

Comment: Easier to answer than to hunt down similar questions, I guess

Comment: Easy isn't always good. :)  Searching [delete in use file](http://superuser.com/search?q=delete+in+use+file) IS pretty easy though. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Moo0 makes a free utility called [FileMonitor](http://www.moo0.com/software/FileMonitor/) that should do exactly this.