# How to force Windows to delete a directory that is in use?

Tags: windows-7, cygwin

I have a directory under `C:\Users\myuser\.ssh` and I need to delete it but Windows won't let me.

From Windows Explorer:

[image: Folder In Use Screenshot]

From a Cygwin shell:

```
myuser@mymachine /cygdrive/c/Users/myuser/.ssh
$ rm -rf id_rsa
rm: cannot remove `id_rsa': Device or resource busy
```

Any ideas how to force this deletion?

Comment: Reboot once, and then delete it?  Stop the process that's accessing it?  What exactly have you tried already?

Comment: Perhaps also see: [Windows 7: File In Use when deleting file](http://superuser.com/questions/73255/windows-7-file-in-use-when-deleting-file)