# How to delete an invincible 0 byte file?

Tags: windows-7

I have a file whose size is 0 bytes. When I try to remove it an error message appears, saying "Could not find file".

Here is the list of things I've tried to delete the file:

- Rebooted
- Reset folder options
- Cleaned the registry with CCleaner
- Using the `del` command
- Replacing it with a different file

The `dir` command gives this information about the file:

```
25.06.2011 21:06 0 STALKER
```

File properties:

[image: asdf]

How can I remove it?

Comment: When you tried Del from the command prompt, did you try `del *.` to delete all files in the folder with no extension?

Comment: @techio007 - since that worked, you should submit it as an Answer and then yoz1k can mark it as correct. This will make it easier for others with the same problem to find help. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't delete pdf file!](http://superuser.com/questions/192234/cant-delete-pdf-file)

Comment: Wait, so `del stalker` didn’t work, but `del *.` did? Are you sure the filename didn’t have a trailing space or something? If you hadn’t deleted it, you would have wanted to bring up its Properties Dialog again, then press `End` in the filename field to see if there are any extra whitespace characters at the end. `;-)`

Comment: @Moab, it’s not the same. That question was about a locked file, this one is not locked, it probably has an invalid filename. That’s why the two questions have completely different answers (and if it *were* locked like in the other question, the command in the solution **wouldn’t have worked**).

Comment: @ synetech inc, My link does say the same thing as this question, "Item not found" and is also a 0 byte file. What more do you want.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try `del *.` from the command prompt while in the folder the file's in.  It will delete all the files in that folder that have no extension.

Comment: Only there isn't any reason why Windows wouldn't be able to display its attributes (time, ACL), just because it has no extension. In this case it's most likely that the file had a trailing dot, which many Win32 programs will choke on.

Comment: This command won't work sometimes. In case it fails, I found another way to delete the file: **1.** Obtain the 8.3 file name with `dir /x` command. **2.** Delete the file with `del problem_file_in_8.3_format`. More information about this: http://superuser.com/questions/388860/why-cant-i-delete-files-that-do-not-exist-but-appear-in-my-download-director.

Comment: This answer does not work for me. Just get the usual file not found error. `dir /x` does not produce another name than `dir`.

Answer (score 19):

Actually the `del *.` doesn't always work. The best answer I have found so far is:

1. Open an elevated command prompt
2. Enter `del "\\?\C:\Users\userX\0bytefile"`

... and voila, the file is deleted. No need to restart or anything else, just need to put `\\?\` before the directory when using the `del` command. Also use the tab button to make sure the name is correct; sometimes a space is added at the end that can be easily missed.

An explanation can be found here: [Why does this file apparently not exist when attempting to delete it?](https://superuser.com/questions/554072)

Comment: This method worked for my file, which could not be deleted using `del *.` or other tricks.

Comment: This approach worked for me.

Comment: This solved the problem I was having with 3 0-byte files that could not be deleted.  Did not even need to elevate the command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you one thing, I've sad on it for about 25 min researching internet for answers and not even solutions here helped, honestly i think people are trying to do it in the worst, most complicated way where there is and easy fix. I remembered old days, win98, xp dealing with the most complicated staff in systems because just wanted do more and more and i remembered back there there was only one best way to actually control all your files on a pc and i just got myself a **[total commander](https://www.ghisler.com/)**.

---

1. Install
2. Run as an Administrator
3. Find the file/folder
4. Delete with your keyboard 'DEL'

**Done!**

Answer (score -2):

You can also try to setup mutiboot with Linux. You can mount your Windows disk and delete it, (as long as it's not encrypted).

I'd recommend [Linux Mint](http://www.linuxmint.co.za). Just download the `.iso` file and burn it to a disk or create a bootable flash drive.