# Removing a file named '...' in Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, filenames

Completely by accident, I created a file named `...` using Grunt.js for Node in Windows 8.

Is it possible to remove this file without having to reformat the partition?

Comment: Yes, it is. It can probably be done with Explorer (it has been a long time since I have seen an unlocked file Explorer can't delete). Failing that, cmd.exe should be able to handle it okay - see `delete`. If both of those fail, grab mingw or cygwin and delete it. But, not programming related ...

Comment: What did you try to remove it and what failed?

Comment: Loss of similar questions, such as http://superuser.com/questions/282194, http://superuser.com/questions/554072 etc. Also see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320081.

Comment: @pnuts: None of the linked questions is about a Linux issue. Basically all questions of this type are similar IMO. The problem is that the GUI restricts the filenames/characters that can be used, but the underlying file system itself doesn't. Thus when you somehow end up with 'invalid' filenames you're stuck unless you use the alternate syntax that bypasses the normal checks, or use another OS such as Linux. (P.S. In my comment above obviously Loss = Lots.)

Comment: @pnuts: I used 'similar' in the sense that the reason for the issue is most likely the same, and so are the solutions. Anyway why the excessive quibbling and hair-splitting? If you notice I didn't choose to mark this question as a dupe of any of the others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `cmd.exe` and type `del \\?\absolutepath`. So if the filename is `C:\tmp\...` then type `del \\?\C:\tmp\...`.

Giving the `\\?\` prefix makes the program use the Unicode version of the Windows file functions. These can handle more filenames than the ANSI versions. The Unicode version for example allows you to create or delete files named `CON`, `PRN` or `NUL` which are old filenames which still have special meaning in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to user2246674 and pnuts answer, I recommend you get "Unlocker" for Windows . It's a nifty little gadget - easy to download, install and use. All of my machines run it. If you have installed it onto your machine in Windows, simply right click the file and then choose "Unlocker" from the menu and then select "Delete" in the left menu options and click on OK.

This tool is quite useful even if something is writing to the file and has accessed it. It will UNLOCK it and you can delete it.