# Trying to delete a file on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

I am having problems trying to delete a file. I think it is a corrupted file, this is its properties dialog:

[image]

As you see, size: 0 bytes and not informatino about creation, last modification or last use access.

This is the dialog I get if I try to delete it:

[image]

Which basically says that the file couldn't be found.

How could I delete this file without having to format the hole drive? (I have already used chkdsk in that drive with no effects)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't delete an invincible 0 byte file](http://superuser.com/questions/332994/cant-delete-an-invincible-0-byte-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open elevated prompt
2. Kill explorer from taskmanager
3. Delete the file forcefully from command-line, after browsing to that location

> cd E:
>
> del carpet*.* /f