# Can't delete downloaded files with no extension - "file not found"

Tags: windows-10

A client emailed me some documents in a zip file. I unzipped them on my Windows 10 PC, but they had no file extension. I manually added a .doc extension, and they opened with Word.

I have another copy of the files with no extension in my One Drive folder.

When I try to delete these files, Windows says it cannot find the file.

If I view the Properties of the file, it says the file is 0KB, but File Explorer says they have a >0 file size.

If I view the `dir` in `CMD` I see the files in question. I was able to rename 1 file in CMD to `filename.txt`, which allowed me to delete the file, but I was unable to rename the rest of the files: `The system cannot find the file specified.`

Never seen this symptom before.

***Update***: The filenames are not special file names.

The following answers did not work in this situation:

- [dir /a /x /p](https://superuser.com/a/463516/34252)
- DEL "FILE NAME IN QUOTES" (not applicable)
- [del `\\?\C:\Users\userX\0bytefile`](https://superuser.com/a/554227/34252)

Comment: See if any of these solutions help: http://superuser.com/questions/332994/how-to-delete-an-invincible-0-byte-file.  Also [Delete Remove 0 byte file Windows 7 64 bit](http://superuser.com/a/463516/364367)

Comment: No luck @fixer1234.

Comment: Yes, I did @fixer1234.

Comment: Run `chkdsk C: /F`, sometimes it helps

Comment: Thanks @PeterHahndorf, I ran that on a reboot, and the issue remains after logging back in.

Comment: You may need dynamite.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command prompt to the dir that the file is in. Move everything else out, then del*.* to remove the problem files.

(with a space after "del", obv. This website wouldn't show the stars if I left the space in...)

Had the same situation just now with a file downloaded from a linux server that had no extension. Tried everything and trusty old stardotstar fixed it.