# How to delete a file with 0 bytes, but read "þa" from it in a c program

Tags: command-line, c, special-characters

This question is not the same as [How to delete an invincible 0 byte file?](https://superuser.com/questions/332994/how-to-delete-an-invincible-0-byte-file) since none of the answers have worked and my impossible to delete file I "feeeel" is different.

I was following this website to delete a folder with a node_modules folder. These take forever to delete using the File Explorer, and I can never remember the exact command to run every time. So I looked it up.

[https://www.ghacks.net/2017/07/18/how-to-delete-large-folders-in-windows-super-fast/#:~:text=Tap%20on%20the%20Windows%2Dkey,F%2FQ%2FS%20*](https://www.ghacks.net/2017/07/18/how-to-delete-large-folders-in-windows-super-fast/#:%7E:text=Tap%20on%20the%20Windows%2Dkey,F%2FQ%2FS%20*).

I use the following command or my fudgy fingers and terrible eyes processed what I thought was: `DEL /F/Q/S *.* > NUL`

This deleted all of the files in the folder, but created this NUL file with 0 bytes. This tells me I messed up the command and something was piped to NUL when the link says `> NUL` is suppose to disable console output.

I've tried File Commander, `del *.`, `del *.*`, `dir /x` doesn't show anything different from `dir`, the delete button in the file explorer, specifying all permissions on the file and trying everything again. Doesn't work.

I tried piping text into it hoping life could get easier if it had something in it. This didn't pipe any text into the file: `echo "Hello world" > NUL`

Being a programmer, I thought I could go deeper and write a c program to delete it. Nope. Didn't work.

```c
       if(remove("C:/../../NUL") == 0)
          printf("Deleted successfully");
       else
          printf("Unable to delete the file");
```

I tried writing text to the file in C and that also failed. Then I tried reading from it and writing the buffer stream to a new file.

```c
       FILE *fp;
       FILE *fp2;
       char buff[255];
       fp = fopen("C:/../../NUL", "r");
       fp2 = fopen("C:/../../cmd.txt", "w");
       fgets(buff, 255, (FILE*)fp);
       fputs(buff, fp2);
       fclose(fp);
       fclose(fp2);
```

I found two characters are in it. þa. No idea what "þa" represents. When I print the characters out to the console in Eclipse there's three of them and they are " aw". The first character is a blocked question mark. It's a little different looking from the Unicode replacement character. So now I'm here and left will a Scooby Doo mystery of these mysterious characters, a fudged command that created these characters, and a file that's unable to be deleted.

For some reason the first character in the string isn't saving so I grabbed some snippets from the Eclipse console output and for some reason Chrome also rendered it differently so I snagged a picture from there too. https://ibb.co/yQSfD8b

--UPDATE--
I ran the command DEL /f/q/s *.* > NULL. Running the flags with lowercase values are what messed me up.

Comment: You found that two characters were in your `buff` variable.  That's not the same as having two characters come from the file.

Comment: I concur, CLEAR your `buff` before you start using it.  `fread()` would probably be more appropriate since you don't know what is actually in there.

Comment: Clearing your buffer before writing to it sounds like a lesson a professor told us that didn't make any sense. Like buying a new car and checking for dead bodies right you purchase it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question has already been answered on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17883481/delete-a-file-named-nul-on-windows).

A shameless copy/paste in case that link should ever die:

Open a command prompt and use these commands to first rename and then delete the NUL file:

```
C:\> rename \\.\C:\..\NUL. deletefile.txt
C:\> del deletefile.txt
```

Using the `\\.\` prefix tells the high-level file I/O functions to pass the filename unparsed to the device driver - this way you can access otherwise invalid names.

Read [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) about valid file / path names in Windows and the various reserved names.

Comment: I wonder what's the role of the trailing dot...also that of ..\

Comment: As far as i know, its part of the filename here. Normally trailing dots are removed for FAT an HPFS filesystem compatibility, however NTFS is posix-compatible, so it supports it. By using \\.\ or \\?\ you disable the standard file normalization. I think the .. is there because its part of the fully qualified path name of NUL and doesnt function as a relative path specifier.

Comment: It is however interesting how the `NUL` file did get created at all? Shouldn't Windows treat the `NUL` filename as special and when output is redirected to `NUL`, just redirect it to the null device (and not create a file named `NUL`), which is what the OP wanted all along?

Comment: Awesome answer! I always find my questions either too vague and specific for anyone to answer, or they already have one. Another case of the latter.

Comment: @Raj, i think they may have typed NUL. instead of NUL when executing the DEL command.