# Windows XP: how to tell who is using a file

Tags: windows-xp, file-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I delete a 'locked' file?](https://superuser.com/questions/13291/how-do-i-delete-a-locked-file)

Sometimes it happens that I can't delete a file because it appears to be in use by some program. Of course there is no obvious process using it (it's not that I don't see VLC playing an AVI I want to erase), so how can I find out what's keeping it busy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a great freeware tool called [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) that can solve this exact problem rather easily.

Comment: No way to do it without installing external programs?

Comment: Process Explorer suggested by @Gilles is interesting too, but accepting this as it more directly solves the specific issue

Comment: You can use LiberKey (www.liberkey.com) to have portable solutions like that without the need of installing them on current system.

Answer (score 6):

Install [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx). Choose “Find / Handle or DLL” in the menu and enter a substring of the file name.

There's also [Handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) if you want a command line interface.

Answer (score -1):

*How to take ownership of a file or a folder in Windows XP*

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=308421

Comment: Taking ownership is not the same as find out what other user/process has the file locked.