# Is there a tool that can Unlock and Delete a file?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer, file-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I delete a 'locked' file?](https://superuser.com/questions/13291/how-do-i-delete-a-locked-file)

I'm looking for a tool that can help me Force unlock a file and then be able to delete it. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/); very helpful tool.

Answer (score 1):

Download  [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) and install . This software will allow you to force unlock a file and then you will able to delete it.