# Cannot delete, rename, copy or move files on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I have a problem about deleting files in windows 7
[image]

What causes it?
here i cannot rename, delete, move, copy the file (picture).
solution please

Comment: What is the name of the full path of that file?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this file is being used by another process.
You can use something like this program [Unlocker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unlocker)

Or in your case trying to decrease length of your filename.

Comment: look here http://superuser.com/questions/13291/how-do-i-delete-a-locked-file?rq=1

Comment: and here some tips http://www.wikihow.com/Delete-a-Locked-File

Comment: I've tried Unlocker1.9.1 but still can not delete

Comment: What about "del filename.png" in command line?

Comment: still can not be deleted, and I've tried http://www.wikihow.com/Delete-a-Locked-File

Comment: and in safe mode?

Comment: I am so sorry, but it still cannot be deleted in safe mode

Comment: hm, last one advice and i give up)) try to dir /x to see valid name e.g file~1.png and in command line try  del file~1.png

Comment: it has a same name when i try dir /x

Comment: try to rename the file, as @IshikawaYoshi said, and to rename the folders of its path... the whole path would be too long...

Comment: change the name of the folder if it still can, but to change the name of the file still can not

Answer (score 0):

From [How to force Windows to rename a file with a special character?](https://superuser.com/questions/31587/how-to-force-windows-xp-to-rename-a-file-with-a-special-character)
It seems that unless the file have a short name, you'll need to boot to Linux to modify it's name.