# how to delete FlashPlayerCPLApp.cpl

Tags: file-permissions, adobe-flash

I'm trying to delete the file C:\Windows\system32\FlashPlayerCPLApp.cpl because of this [link](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/967408) to do a clean Flash Player install. However I am having problems deleting it. It says: cannot delete FlashPlayerCPLApp: Access is denied. Make sure the disk is not full or write-protected and that the file is not currently in use. How do I delete this file???

Comment: Does your user have administrator access? What version of Windows? Is UAC on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Flash Player Uninstaller for uninstalling it: http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/uninstall-flash-player-windows.html

If for some reason it doesn't work, GeneQ gave a wonderful solution to a similar problem: https://superuser.com/a/13303/155919

Also, make sure that you have administrative privileges.