# How to unlock lost file handles?

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, ntfs

I'm a developer and sometimes my IDE crash leaving a huge cache file locked. When I restart my IDE I can't compile because the file is locked and can't be removed.

My solution to the problem now is to reboot, but it takes time and then all my zillions of open web pages are gone too.

There must be a way to manually unlock a file somehow so I can delete it. Yes, I'm aware of the risks, but this file is 100% guaranteed to only be used by my IDE.

The file is not shared and resides on my local drive in NTFS format, so openfiles.exe will not be of use here...

(This isn't a duplicate of [How do I delete a locked file](https://superuser.com/questions/13291/how-do-i-delete-a-locked-file) because the process is already dead)

Comment: Try Unlocker. it has helped me with this issue in past. it is filebased instead of focusing on the process that locked the file. http://www.filehippo.com/download_unlocker/

Comment: @FrankThomas I used the Process Explorer to track it down and kill it.

Comment: that would have been my first suggestion, if you hadn't indicated that the process was already dead and thus was different from the linked question. since it has no installer procexp is definitely the superior option, as long as the lock isn't persistent after the process is aborted.

Comment: @FrankThomas With process explorer I found out that there was a "hidden" process still holding it, even after my whole IDE process was killed. So even if I thought there was no process holding it, it turned out there was one after all...

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to download [Process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) from microsoft. I used "Find->Find Handle or DLL..." and entered the full file name.

Then I could kill it...