# How to get the names of the programs which are accessing a certain file/folder and blocking any other access to it?

Tags: windows-7, file-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tool to determine what has locked a file](https://superuser.com/questions/6607/tool-to-determine-what-has-locked-a-file)

Sometime when I delete a file/folder, Windows 7 tells me that the file is accessed by other program and cannot be deleted. I close all the processes as much as I can but it is still blocked.

So, I wanna get a list of program that are accessing one file/folder. How can I do this in Windows 7?

Answer (score 3):

[Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) will do that.

It also lets you unlock the file with or without killing the locking process, and delete the file.

It's nicer than handle because it integrates into explorer.exe (adds an option to the right click menu).

(Note: deleting locked files can cause things to crash, if a program is in the process of using the file. On the other hand, sometimes programs hold file handles open well after they are actually done with the file (explorer.exe, I'm looking at you), so sometimes you can't really avoid using an unlocking utility.)

Answer (score 0):

I use process explorer for this purpose all the tome. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Use [Handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx).

> Ever wondered which program has a
>   particular file or directory open? Now
>   you can find out. Handle is a utility
>   that displays information about open
>   handles for any process in the system.
>   **You can use it to see the programs that have a file open**, or to see the
>   object types and names of all the
>   handles of a program.