# How can I find out which process is using a file in a directory that I am trying to delete?

Tags: windows-7, task-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tool to determine what has locked a file](https://superuser.com/questions/6607/tool-to-determine-what-has-locked-a-file)

On Windows 7 I am trying to delete a directory in Windows explorer, however when I try, it tells me a file in that directory is being "used by a process" and therefore cannot be deleted at this time.

**How can I find out which process is using the file so I can terminate it in the task manager?**

Comment: Have you tried rebooting?

Answer (score 8):

I use Process Explorer for this http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653

In the Find menu, "Find Handle or DLL" will allow you to locate the offending process.

Comment: The Sysinternals utilities really are good, no malware, no install, no  'crap', just pure utility.

Answer (score 1):

Download and use Unlocker application to see which process is locked your application.
http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/Unlocker.shtml